# Calling a View from another View

Tags: zend-framework

I have a **login.phtml view** that would like to put in a common path and get it accessed by any module through the application.

For sidebars rendered by `$this->render('common/sidebar.phtnl')` it works since my layout is a single one for all modules.

But when it comes to the content `$this->layout()->content`, if I add a helper to the result view like `$this->login()` Zend keeps looking for it on the module scripts path.

How can it be possible to make my content view render another common view througth a helper even if my flow is a result of a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good job for a [custom view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.custom). Writing your own is very easy and once you've tried it you won't be able to stop!

Your custom view helper should go in applications/views/helpers/NameOfHelper.php and should have a public method called nameOfHelper(). I'll use login as an example as that is your use case on this occassion.

First create applications/views/helpers/Login.php:-

```
class Zend_View_Helper_Login extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function login()
    {
        return "Logging in!";
    }
}
```

Then in the view or layout simply do:-

```
echo $this->login();
```

and get the output:-

> Logging in!

Couldn't be easier!

Alternatively if you want to use a view script you can do this in your login() method:-

```
class Zend_View_Helper_Login extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function login()
    {
        $this->view->exampleVar = 'example value';
        return $this->view->render('login.phtml')
    }
}
```

Then when you do `echo $this->login()` in your view or layout you will see the output you want.

Obviously, you can put whatever code you want into the login() method.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It is very easy to understand!

Answer (score 0):

From view script you can:

```
<?php echo  $this->render("menus/recetas.phtml"); ?>
```