# zend layout where do placeholders go?

Tags: zend-framework, placeholder

I've read over this article about placeholders. Previously, i was including a bunch of files into my view scripts. after time that become complicated as i had to account for context and there isn't a really good solution.

I'm guessing this is where placeholders come in. I've read over the [zend article](http://devzone.zend.com/1235/view-helpers-in-zend-framework/). None of the articles i've read are very specific as to where i place my placeholders. in what folder should they go in?

Forgive me i'm still very confused with zend.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9264520/212940 and see if it helps. I linked it as the article you link to is about view helpers, not placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your will capture a block somewhere in controller/view then you'll display it in the template/layout.

I think this [Zend Doc example makes more sense](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.placeholder).

```
// before the view is displayed
// you can use other methods to render the templates into placeholder for later use
<?php $this->placeholder('foo')->set("Some text for later") ?>

// most like somewhere in the view
<?php
    echo $this->placeholder('foo');
    // outputs "Some text for later"
?>
or 
<?= $this->placeholder('sidebar') ?>
```